# PromiseKit Cannot invoke 'fulfill' with an argument list of type '(Data)'

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest, promisekit

I'm trying to get data from the network request using PromiseKit in the following code below, but on the line `seal.fulfill(data)` I'm getting the error 'Cannot invoke 'fulfill' with an argument list of type '(Data)''. Can anyone please give me a hint on what am I doing wrong?

```
import Foundation
import PromiseKit

class NetworkService {
    
    let baseHost: String = "api.someAwesomeSite.com"
    var version: String { return "3.345" }
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    
    func getData<Data>(method: String, queryItems: [URLQueryItem] = []) -> Promise<Data> {
        var urlConstructor = URLComponents()
        urlConstructor.scheme = "https"
        urlConstructor.host = self.baseHost
        urlConstructor.path = "/method/\(method)"
        
        urlConstructor.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "user_id", value: ApiManager.session.userId),
            URLQueryItem(name: "access_token", value: ApiManager.session.token),
            URLQueryItem(name: "v", value: version),
        ]
        
        urlConstructor.queryItems?.append(contentsOf: queryItems)
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: urlConstructor.url!)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        
        return Promise<Data> { seal in
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, apiError) in
                
                if let error = apiError {
                    seal.reject(error)
                }
                
                if let data = data {
                    seal.fulfill(data)
                }
                }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just a little confused with your generic arguments. Change:

```swift
    func getData<Data>(method: String, queryItems: [URLQueryItem] = []) -> Promise<Data> {
```

to

```swift
    func getData(method: String, queryItems: [URLQueryItem] = []) -> Promise<Data> {
```

The problem was that when you have `Data` as a generic type argument, the compiler is thinks `Data` is some type you will define... but within the function you are also using `Data` to refer to the Swift library `Data` type and it can't be both things at the same time.